# Anciens manuels scolaires

Tags: ressources

Existe-t-il un site duquel on peut télécharger (gratuitement et légalement) des manuels (français, mathématiques, sciences, grec, latin, etc), des grammaires, etc (pour école primaire, collège, lycée) des anciens programmes scolaires (années 1970-2000) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Une petite recherche m'a fourni :

- https://www.liberte-scolaire.com/articles/analyses/un-tresor-de-manuels-scolaires-anciens-a-explorer-de-toute-urgence/
- https://manuelsanciens.blogspot.com/